# how to get file name from sdcard and saving in database android and show it as listview

Tags: android, database, sd-card

I am saving audio files to a specific folder in sd card, now i want to get the name of those files and save their name and other information to database and show them as list view...cannot find any solution, please help.

Comment: is not that better if you save file name in database at the time of saving audio file to sdcard  ?

Comment: Hi Kalpesh i guess u r right can u help me please with some kind of tutorial or code, i would be very greatful

Answer (score 1):

Hi Use below code.

```
  List<String> list=new ArrayList<string>();
// String path="/mnt/sdcard/audiofilesfolder/"; 
        File folder = new File(path);


        listOfFiles = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles());


            if(listOfFiles.size()>0)
            {


           for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles.size(); j++) {


         System.out.println(" j " + listOfFiles.get(j).getAbsolutePath());
         list.add((listOfFiles.get(j).getAbsolutePath()));
     }
```

Then use the list and grab the items added from that and show it in the list view  .
Hope this will help you.